# Loshon ho'rah with a spouse

Tags: loshon-hara

Can one speak loshon ho'rah with his wife if it is for the purpose of making small talk and showing interest in his wife in order to improve (or maintain ) shalom bayis?

Comment: Mark, please be sure to search the site first before asking a new question to see if we've addressed your question before.

Comment: @DoubleAA. That question was about relieving stress and benefitting in some tangible way. I've seen in the poskim many that permit that. I specifically am asking about a lower level benefit such as "small talk" or just to make conversation so that a little life or conversation is added to the relationship.